# Regex not able to find repeating tokens in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi I know this question has been asked a number of times. I used the same method as suggested by someone at SO for finding repeating expressions using regex, but its not working correctly. I have a pattern file like following which I need to parse in Java using regex.

```
[Abc]
var1 = "val1"
var2 = val2 
[Def]
var1 = "\[val1\]" 
var2 = 1;
var3 = val3
[Xyz]
var1 = val1
```

I am using a regex `(\[([^\\]*?)\])(.|\s)*?` to find blocks in file. I am considering a block from start of square bracket to start of next bracket. When I try this regex at [regex planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) it doesn't work. It matches the given file but it finds group(3) to be null which should be the block from end of first square bracket to the start of next square bracket. 
I also tried using this regex `(\[([^\\]+?)\]\s*$\s*(([^=]*)\s*=\s*([^$]*)\s*$)*?)` but this also doesn't work. 
When I fixed the value pair number to 4 and tried using regex `(\[(.+?)\]\s*?(.+?)\s*?=\s*?(.+?)\s*?(.+?)\s*?=\s*?(.+?)\s*?(.+?)\s*?=\s*?(.+?)\s*?(.+?)\s*?=\s*?(.+?)\n\s*?)` it worked. Why it is not working with the variable case.

I would like both if I am able to extract block in above case example of block would be

```
var1 = "val1"
var2 = val2
```

or directly extract

```
var1 , "val1" var2 val2
```

Hope this makes the question clear.

Comment: So I understand the output from that input would be `[val1\]`?

Comment: @m0skit0 output should be token Abc then val1 then val2 and so on.

Comment: @Keppil I tried that but it still doesn't match

Comment: ?? You said *"to find blocks in file. I am considering a block from start of square bracket to start of next bracket"*. `val1`? You mean val1\. I don't see any such `[val1]` value in your input (but there's `[val\]`). Same goes for `val2` (there's no `[val2]`)

Comment: Try `^\[.*[\s*].*[^[]*` remember to enable multi-line.

Comment: @m0skit0 Sorry for being unclear I have edited question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use positive look ahead. 
You need to find the next block start, but without catching it.

Something along

```
(\[([^\\]*?)\])((.*\s)*?)(?=(\[[^\\]*\])|$)
```

Explained:

- `(\[([^\\]*?)\])` - the block definition: [sdgsdg]
- `((.*\s)*?)` - the block contents. Lines, but not greedy.
- `(?=(\[[^\\]*\])|$)` - the positive look ahead. Start of another block, or end of string.

Comment: @Nikola K. I am unable to execute this on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html because it times out. It might be very slow.